# ImageMagick Corrupt JPEG Data While Removing Metadata in Python Subprocess

Tags: python, imagemagick, subprocess, jpeg

I'm trying to use Python subprocess and ImageMagick to remove metadata from an uploaded test jpeg file.

When using the ImageMagick CLI, the metadata removal process works perfectly

`$ mogrify -strip -auto-orient ~/Project/test.jpg`

Note that `mogrify` is the same as `convert` except it saves over the original file.

When I use Python subproccess, the image becomes corrupted along the edges.

[image: Image with corruption]

Fortunately, there is an error recorded in the error log:

```
[cgi:error] mogrify.exe: Premature end of JPEG file `../www/user-images/test.jpg' 
[cgi:error] mogrify.exe: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `../www/user-images/test.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.\r
[cgi:error] mogrify.exe: Premature end of JPEG file `../www/user-images/test.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.\r
[cgi:error] mogrify.exe: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `../www/user-images/test.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.\r
[cgi:error] mogrify.exe: Corrupt JPEG data: found marker 0xd9 instead of RST5 `test.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.\r
```

Without ImageMagick, the image is uploaded perfectly.

The Python script:

```
import cgi, os, sys, shutil, subprocess, logging
from subprocess import CalledProcessError

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form['test_file']

image_path = "test.jpg"

with open(image_path, 'wb') as current_file:
    # Copy file contents to new file
    shutil.copyfileobj(fileitem.file, current_file)

    # Remove metadata
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(['C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\mogrify.exe', '-strip', '-auto-orient', image_path])
    except CalledProcessError:
        logging.error("Error encountered while processing image")
```

I tested this with different parameters (or no parameters!) and mogrify seems to damage the file in some way. Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Would the file be corrupt of if use `convert.exe source.jpg -strip -auto-orient out.jpg` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix! I needed to close the file before I could run ImageMagick.

```
with open(image_path, 'wb') as current_file:
    # Copy file contents to new file
    shutil.copyfileobj(fileitem.file, current_file)

# CLOSE THE FILE BEFORE USING SUBPROCESS
try:
    subprocess.check_output(['C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\mogrify.exe', '-strip', '-auto-orient', image_path])
except CalledProcessError:
    logging.error("Error encountered while processing image")
```

Now the metadata has been removed without corruption.

Comment: unrelated: use raw string literals for Windows paths: `r'C:\Users\nova'`

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that